# How to send emails to the subscriber?

Tags: rules, flags

I have two content types movie types(say comedy, horror, action are node titles) and movies. where I am using movie types node titles as a node reference in the movies content type. here user can subscribe to the movie types and can watch all the movies under the type. Now where i am stuck is to send a mail to the subscriber when new movie is uploaded under the type he/she subscribed. Please help me to sort out this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Subscriptions](https://drupal.org/project/subscriptions).

> This module enables users to subscribe to be notified of changes to nodes or taxonomies, such as new comments in specific forums, or additions to some category of blog. Once enabled, all nodes will have an additional link that allows the user to change their subscriptions. Users have tab on their user screen to manage their own subscriptions. Users can also set an auto-subscribe function which notifies the user if anyone comments on posts they have made. Admins can turn this on by default.

It provides a very powerful and flexible subscription framework, and there are many ways to configure subscriptions with this module.

One that probably will match your use case is to use taxonomy terms for the type of movie (comedy, horror, action, etc.) and let the users subscribe to the type of movie they're interested in by taxonomy term.

Comment: Thanks, But I want the creator who can create his/her own channel and can upload videos under which. When creator creates a channel it automatically should be appended to the node reference list in movie content type. And I want to do this task with the help of flags and rules. so that i can make minimal use of modules. Thanks,

Comment: If this is what you want, then that should have been stated so in your question.  To get an answer that suits your requirements, you need to be specific about what you require.